# Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:generateDebugApolloIR' (type 'ApolloIRGenTask')

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio, build.gradle

I've updated my gradle version to latest version and now my project is not able to build. The following errors are being shown on logcat while building project.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:generateDebugApolloIR' (type 'ApolloIRGenTask').
  - In plugin 'com.amazonaws.appsync' type 'com.apollographql.apollo.gradle.ApolloIRGenTask' field 'extension' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Internal.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
```

I've tried to rebuild project, clean project, invalidate caches. But still having the same issue.
My build.gradle Project Level:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.17.1'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10'
    classpath 'com.amplifyframework:amplify-tools-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'
    classpath "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync-gradle-plugin:3.1.0"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

build.gradle app level

```
//AWS
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:1.29.0' //updated
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-api:1.28.3' //updated
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-datastore:1.28.3' //updated
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:3.1.1' //updated 
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.35.0' //updated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your library versions

build gradle project level

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.17.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10'
        classpath 'com.amplifyframework:amplify-tools-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'
        classpath "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync-gradle-plugin:3.3.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

build gradle app level

```
//AWS
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:1.31.3' //updated 1.31.3
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-api:1.28.3' //updated
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-datastore:1.28.3' //updated
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:3.3.0' //updated 3.3.0
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.40.0' //updated 2.40.0
```

build project now, it will work

Comment: let me check, ill let you know